# ACL on a windows Share

Tags: c#, windows, acl, ntfs

I am creating an app which create directories on a windows share.
I apply ACL on it with this code :

```
ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(managersSID, FileSystemRights.Traverse | FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.ListDirectory | FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes | FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

All ACLs seems applyed (I can see in the security tab of the folder) but when I try to click on teh folder I have a windows error "You don't have the rights to open this folder".

managersSID is the SID of the Mangers groups which I am in.

**I want to apply the read-only access to this folder did I use the good flags ?**

Maybe I do not understand all the subtlety of the inheritance ?